# Pygame Collision Explained

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I am brand new to Python/Pygame.  I have been able to piece together a few things in small test programs but trying to get a grasp of collision is just not happening.  I've tried working through multiple tutorials but I feel like I need it completely broken down before I get a good sense of it.

Can someone explain how something like colliderect(Rect) works?
Do I need a class for the collide functions or can I just take two rectangles and get a result?

The code I am trying to work with is below.  I was able to make two images, each surrounded by a rect, I am assuming the collision only works with sprites and not images?  I can control one of the images with my mouse, and the would like to trigger a collision detection when I mouse over and click on the static image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thx

~T

```
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

size=width, height= 600,400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

rageface = pygame.image.load("rageface.jpg")
rageface = pygame.transform.scale(rageface,(100,100))
rageface2 = pygame.transform.scale(rageface,(100,100))

black = (100,0,0)
green = (0,150,150)
r=0
x=50
y=50
mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx,my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    #colliderect(Rect) ????????????????????

    screen.fill((r,0,0))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [50, 50, 250, 100], 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [mx-50, my-50, 250, 100], 0)
    screen.blit(rageface2,(mx-50,my-50))
    screen.blit(rageface,(x,y))


    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`colliderect` works like this:

```
rect1.colliderect(rect2)
```

This will return `True` if the two rects are colliding, `False` otherwise.

here is the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

`colliderect` is a method of the pygame `Rect` class, sprites also have collision methods

In pygame an image that is loaded is a surface just like the pygame screen/display,  to get a rect from a surface you use:

```
Surface.get_rect()
```

So to get one for say `rageface` just do `rage_rect = rageface.get_rect()` and now you can use `rage_rect` like a rect

Tell me if this is clear or if you need more help!

Comment: Very cool!  Thank you.  That is just what I needed.  :)  I got it to work.  For some reason when I use the surface.get_rect the colliderect is returning true before I actually move the images over each other.  Anyway, I'll keep messing around with it and see what I can do.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, No problem, Pygame can be a bit confusing at first but once you get the hang of it it's really fun! Good luck!